# How to send a request to public website which uses POST method and how to find out parameters of the request like source and destination etc

Tags: c#, javascript, php, post, httprequest

I want to collect data of trains for the given 'source and destination' pairs from an public website. 
I don't want to do this manually, but from the code and automate it. I know it uses POST method. But how do i send my input to the page? i don't know post parameters it uses! Is it possible anyway how to find this.. solutions are much appreciated.

Comment: fiddler, httpwebrequest (c#), reading up on http protocol. Then getting IP banned for TOS violation!!

Answer (score 1):

Best solution woud be to use their API if they provide it otherwise i would be carfull taking information from the site without their permission.

Answer (score 1):

Use the site like you normally would with the network tab in your browser's dev tools open. When the site makes the request, you can inspect the headers and body of the request. If they didn't release an api they probably don't want you doing this though.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to incorporate post-receive programming similar to that used for Github webhooks for your program. 
Take a look here:
https://github.com/aegypius/github-webhook-php